# Macbook Pro Sleep Battery Drain

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I have an Early 2011 Macbook Pro (13", basic spec) which since I got it (I only just stopped to think about it) has had a massive amount of sleep battery drain.

When the laptop is on and in-use, its battery lasts pretty much as I'd expect (5-7 hours) but if I put it to sleep (no apps running in foreground, RescueTime, Dropbox, Delibar and Droplr in background) it'll flatten its battery from 100% in about 24 hours.

The background apps are exactly the same as the ones running on my 2010 pro, the machines are all but identically setup, but that one in any 24-hour off period gets through about 4% of its battery. Both machines also have FileVault enabled and are running the same build of Lion.

Is there anything I can do to test the cause of this, or should I take it to a genius to inspect?

Comment: Does the white power light on the front pulse when your believe the Mac is asleep?

Comment: It does, a gentle slow pulse.

Comment: Consider calibrating your MacBook Pro's battery and then time the battery drain again. These instruction's from Apple will help with the calibration: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1490

Comment: Have done that one, and since I upgraded it to mountain lion the waking battery drain has been pretty terrible too - I'm down from nearly 7 hours to a little over three. Thinking it might be time for a genius visit.

Comment: I'm also considering a genius visit. I think my battery is not at peek performance and I just bought my laptop a week ago. It gets about 4-5 hours life rather than the advertised 10. And I set my energy saver stats at the tested stats on apple.com. I'll have to see if this persists.

Comment: I just found out that if you keep the bluetooth on, even when nothing is connected, it will drain the battery even during sleep mode. Once I turned it off, my battery has lasted at least 7 hours on a full charge.

Comment: Your Mac doesn't happen to support Power Nap through some tweak, does it? Check System Preferences > Energy Saver to see if Power Nap is an option there. If it is, that could be part of the problem.

Comment: @GeorgePearce Did you ever find a solution? I have the same issue on a 2017 MacBook. Driving me crazy...